# "Freeze" scrolling while fixed image background, with skrollr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/azzy588u/12/# 
I need the scrolling "pause" you see in the 2nd synth, but I want to have the parallax effect that the position is fixed and the image scrolls fixed like in this website: https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/, so i want that effect with the divs.

I am using skrollr.js

```
<div id="slides-container">
  <div id="slides" data-0="transform:translate(0%,0%);" data-150p="transform:translate(0%,-50%);" data-200p="" data-350p="transform:translate(0%,-100%);" data-450p="" data-550p="transform:translate(0%,-150%);">
    <div id="slide-1" class="slide">
      <div class="caption" data-40p="opacity: 1; transform:translate(0px,0px);" data-70p="opacity: 0; transform:translate(0px,-100%);" data-anchor-target="#helper">
        <h1>Image 1 Title</h1>
        <p>Image description goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="slide">
      <div class="caption" data-130p="opacity: 0; transform:translate(0px,-200%);" data-180p="opacity: 1; transform:translate(0px,0px);" data-250p="" data-280p="opacity: 0; transform:translate(-100px,0px);" data-anchor-target="#helper">
        <h1>Image 2 Title</h1>
        <p>Image description goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3" class="slide">
      <div class="caption" data-250p="opacity: 0; transform:translate(300px,0px);" data-300p="opacity: 1; transform:translate(0px,0px);" data-anchor-target="#helper">
        <h1>Image 3 Title</h1>
        <p>Image description goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4" class="slide">
      <div class="caption" data-430p="opacity: 0;" data-450p="opacity: 1;" data-anchor-target="#helper">
        <h1>Image 4 Title</h1>
        <p>Image description goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="helper">
  <div class="marker red"></div>
  <div class="marker green"></div>
  <div class="marker blue"></div>
  <div class="marker yellow"></div>
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
#slides-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* double the height/width of a viewport */
#slides {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.slide {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#slide-1 {

    background: url('../img/synth-bg-1.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}
#slide-2 {

    background: url('../img/synth-bg-2.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;

    -webkit-transform: translate(0,100%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,100%);
    transform: translate(0,100%);
}
#slide-3 {

    background: url('../img/synth-bg-3.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;

    -webkit-transform: translate(0%,200%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%,200%);
    transform: translate(00%,200%);
}
#slide-3 .caption {
    left: 5%;
    right: auto;
    color: #47373f;
}
#slide-4 {

    background: url('../img/synth-bg-4.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;

    -webkit-transform: translate(0%,300%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%,300%);
    transform: translate(0%,300%);
}
#slide-4 .caption {
    right: auto;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: auto;
    color: #47373f;
}
```

Comment: So you want the synths to parallax scroll, or all of them to have a bit of stop, or both?

Comment: @rac Both, I know how to do the stop here but not the parrallax combined with the stop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be learn more about `skrollr` plugin. This plugin is patern based. You can check when your element (number patern) stop.

**UPDATE**

Please try: http://jsfiddle.net/jteh4u6j/3/ or snippet below.

```js
var s = skrollr.init();
```

```css
 ==========================================================================
   Chrome Frame prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
}
p, h1 { margin: 0; }
h1 { margin-bottom: 0.2em; }
p { line-height: 1.333em; }
 
/* full width/height container */
#slides-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
/* double the height/width of a viewport */
#slides {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.slide {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#slide-1 {
 
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/7aWoXGR.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;

}
#slide-2 {
 
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/GkPXSPP.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    height:0%;
}
#slide-3 {
 
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/EQabH21.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    height:0%;
}
#slide-3 .caption {
    left: 5%;
    right: auto;
    color: #47373f;
}
#slide-4 {
   height:0%;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/GWz6iqB.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#slide-4 .caption {
    right: auto;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: auto;
    color: #47373f;
}

#helper {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    height:600%;
    width: 0;
}
.marker {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Image replacement
 */

.ir {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* IE 6/7 fallback */
    *text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ir:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 150%;
}

/*
 * Hide from both screenreaders and browsers: h5bp.com/u
 */

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v
 */

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element to be focusable
 * when navigated to via the keyboard: h5bp.com/p
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

/*
 * Hide visually and from screenreaders, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
    
    /* =Caption style */
    .caption {
        text-align: right;
    }
    #slide-3 .caption,
    #slide-4 .caption {
        text-align: left;
    }
}

@media print,
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid required HTTP connection: h5bp.com/r
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
     */

    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}

/* 
 Ok so you have made it this far, that means you are very keen to on my code. 
 Anyway I don't really mind it. This is a great way to learn so you actually doing the right thing:)
 Follow me @ihatetomatoes
*/
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.27/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>

        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

  <!-- Demo content -->   
  <div id="page-content">
            
            <div id="slides-container">
                <div id="slides" data-0="transform:translate(0%,0%);" data-1500="transform:translate(0%,0%);">
                    <div id="slide-1" class="slide"  
                    data-0="transform:translate(0%,0%);" data-1500="transform:translate(0%,0%);">
                       
                    </div>
                    <div id="slide-2" class="slide" 
                    data-0="height:  0%" data-500="height:  100%">
                    </div>
                    <div id="slide-3" class="slide" 
                    data-500="height:  0%" data-900="height:  100%">
                    </div>
                    <div id="slide-4" class="slide" 
                    data-900="height:  0%" data-1200="height:  100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="helper">
                <div class="marker red"></div>
                <div class="marker green"></div>
                <div class="marker blue"></div>
                <div class="marker yellow"></div>
            </div>





  </div>
  <!-- /Demo content -->

        <!-- Include Skrollr.js -->
     

    </body>
```